# Configure Linux ec2 server for React web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, webserver

I have a simple react.js app that runs fine on my local windows pc.
npm start etc... I've done my build npm build etc...
Now I want to install/run the app on an Amazon Linux ec2 server.
I have created the instance, installed node & npm.
I've created an ftp connection so as to move my code to the server.

My questions are as follows:

1. Do I need any additional installs? (web server?)
2. Where exactly do I move my code to, to see it actually run?

Thanks, I'm reasonably new to react, but not coding or servers, but used to windows.
Thanks for any pointers. Respectfully.